# Body, HTML min-height:100% does not get the entire height

Tags: html, css, sass

I've been trying this approach although I'm facing a problem, I got a ~10px margin on the bottom of my footer. I've been set on both html and body:

```
html{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px dashed blue; 
}
body {
  background: #fafafa;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

[image: White space gap]

But still this is not working out. Ive tryed an approach with overflow:scroll but it gives me an inner scrollbar

[image: Inner scrollbar]

*I know theres some related topics here on stackoverflow but none worked to get rid of that white gap"

Thanks!! =)

Comment: Remove the `min-height` from the `html` and `body` and try `height:100vh;` on the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The issue is, I was setting the footer with a `height: 20px;` I dont know why but its thinner than it must have to work properly. When I set it thicker like to `height: 35px;` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach by removing height: 100% to height:100vh;

```
height:100vh;
```

or

```
min-height:100vh;
```

So as to sets the background to the full height of the viewport.